# How to use JS object/classes to save repeating html

Tags: javascript, class

First I'm brand new to JS but have an idea that object classes are what I should be looking into, yet I can't find a straightforward tutorial that doesn't shoot off into arrays,arguments or silly alert boxes! All I'm looking for is something like this:

```
<head>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
function Class (color, bodypart, item)

Var1 =newClass ('red', 'hand', 'ball')
Var2 =newClass ('green', 'foot, 'bat')
```

btw I have hundreds of these Vars to write, this is the reason for looking into this method

then put these Vars into some HTML:
    `('<div><span style="color:'+color+';>'+bodypart+'</span><br/>'+item+'</div><br/>');</script></head>`

now in the body I want to call one of the Vars (e.g. Var1) and put it (with the HTML) into a div so it would automatically generate:

```
<div><span style="color:red;">hand</span><br/>item</div><br/>
```

My question:what exactly do I put in the head and body to make this happen??

I'm guessing something to do with GetElementById, Classes, etc but I can't find the right syntax to make a simple example work.

Aaaaany help would be fantastically appreciated for such a noob! (p.s. I have spent the last full 2 days reading tutorials and forum posts but they keep losing me in far more complex things than I can grasp)

Comment: Rather than using raw client-side JavaScript (document.getElementById) you should consider using one of the many popular 3rd party libraries.  There are many advantages to this.  My favorite is jQuery:  www.jquery.com

Comment: Do it on the server. By the time you get all the data a script together and send it, you may as well just generate the markup and send that. And the language attribute for script element is deprecated, the type attribute is required.

Comment: @RobG In HTML5, the `type` attribute is [only required if you aren't using JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

Comment: @Brandan-HTML5 is not a standard, HTML 4 is. The [type attribute is required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) for valid markup, though in practice it is not needed unless some other scripting language is also used in the same page (even if one of those languages is javasrcript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound like you're in over your head at this point, and if you plan on doing a lot of javascript, you're much better off finishing off those tutorials on arrays and such.

Having said that, to help you jump ahead a little, here's what you need to do:

- Go to http://www.jquery.com and follow the instructions on how to include jQuery onto your page
- Write a javascript function that uses jQery to transform a javascript array into your html

That function might look something like:

```
var parts = [
  ['red', 'hand', 'ball'],
  ['green', 'foot', 'ball']
];

makePart = function(part){
  var div = $('<div />');
  var span = $('<span />').css({color:part[0]}).text(part[1]);
  div.append( span );
  div.append( $('<br />') );
  div.append( part[2] );
  $('body').append( div ).append( $('<br />') );
}

// this next line makes all your parts
$.each( parts, function(index, part) { makePart(part); } );

// while this would only make the first part
makePart( parts[0] );
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much to you all for replying and Chris your example has already taught me so much. I'll fix my attention on JQuery.  Any clues as to what terms I should be researching to learn how to call just the parts[0] line (i.e. red,hand,ball) in one Div, and just the parts[1] line (ie. green, hand, ball) in another Div?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I'd say you need to focus on what the $ function is doing (creating a new div element, or selecting the body element), and what the append function does (sets an element to be the child of another element). As you go through the documentation, you'll see other related function in the library that you may need to get your final design.

Comment: Oh OK, but I've bugged you enough! I understand everything in your example just not how to actually pull only 'red,hand,ball' variables on one part of  my site and only 'green,foot,ball' variables on another part of the site.  But don't worry I'll do a lot more research so I can explain myself better as I certainly don't know the terminology even though I pick up the logic quickly! Cheers again for your great help!

Comment: No worries. I've split up the example to show how the actual function for only converting one part would look like, and left two examples of either adding every part to the page, or only adding a single part.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again for your patience! You could've just said rtfm and I would have given up as my site is 99% css & html but I think your example will stop my site from being ludicrously HTML bloated. You're a star!

Comment: any chance to ask you a last 2 questions but maybe in chat as it says 'Please avoid extended discussions in comments'? Just 2 questions... ;)

Comment: Well, I'm glad to help, but you're much better off asking the questions as new questions: that way the rest of the community can benefit from the answers, and you're more likely to get a comprehensive answer as other people will contribute to. Don't be shy, ask more questions. Oh, and don't forget to accept answers!

Comment: Ok thanks I've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361553/populate-specific-div-from-particular-jquery-array

Comment: It's all working great now, theres a jsfiddle over at the above link. Thank you for starting me off on JQuery I'm going to explore it in more depth now I can see a working model. Thanks again for your patience with me

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of templating libraries around that will turn arrays of data into DOM structures. However, if your requirements are simple then you can put the data into an array and iterate over it to generate HTML or DOM elements:

```
var data = [
             ['red', 'hand', 'ball'],
             ['green', 'foot', 'bat']
           ];

function genElements(data) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  var br = document.createElement('br');
  var b, d, s, x;

  for (var i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    x = data[i];
    d = frag.appendChild(div.cloneNode());
    s = d.appendChild(span.cloneNode());
    s.style.color = x[0];
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x[1]));
    div.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    frag.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    alert(frag.childNodes.length);
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can generate HTML and insert that:

```
function genElements(data) {
  var html = [];
  var x;

  for (var i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    x = data[i];
    html.push('<div><span style="color:' + x[0] + '">' +
              x[1] + '</span><br>' + x[2] + '</div><br>');
  }
  return html.join('');
}
```

Then insert it wherever is appropriate. But you could do exactly the same logic on the server and just send the HTML, avoiding all the issues with client side scripting. Overall it would be much more efficient and robust.

Comment: I see, thanks Rob.  By server-side scripting I'm guessing php etc, but I'm trying to stick to css, html and some form of JS, and was looking for a way to prevent hard-coding hundreds of Divs that contain the same HTML but with different variables I mentioned. Can you recommend any terms that I should be researching to achieve what you have mentioned?