# Populate specific Div from particular Jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays, dom

How to output a particular JQuery array into a particular Div.   For example I want to pull the (phrases[0]) array into Div id="div01", and the (phrases[1]) array into Div id="div02".  I have read up all the functions of JQuery but can't find this.

```
var phrases = [
['nihao', 'orange', '你 好', 'hello'],
['zaijian', 'red', '你 好', 'goodbye']
];

makePhrase = function(phrase){
var div = $('<div class="word"><span class="pinyin">' +phrase[0]+ '</span><br/><span class="chinese">'     +phrase[2]+ '</span><br/><span class="english">' +phrase[3]+ '</span> </div>');
```

And then I need a line to say (in effect):

> .append makePhrase( phrases[0] ) to Div id="div01"

but do not know the correct method.  This is only my second day of learning JQuery so I would appreciate a spell-it-out answer which then I can learn more from through further investigation! I hate being the noob but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.append` seems to be the right method. Why don't you have a look at some examples? http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: $("#div01").append(makePhrase(prases[0]))

Comment: I'm obviously missing a basic JQuery thing here because I can't get @mshsayem 's code to work, though this is the only one that seems to reference div01 as the target which is what I'm after.  Here is the jsfiddle for it - what am I missing?  http://jsfiddle.net/SKssF/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close; Try this:

```
var phrases = [
    ['nihao', 'orange', '你 好', 'hello'],
    ['zaijian', 'red', '你 好', 'goodbye']
    ];

makePhrase = function(phrase) {
    var div = '<div class="word"><span class="chinese">Chinese: ' + phrase[0] + '</span><br/><span class="pinyin">Pinyin:' + phrase[2] + '</span><br/><span class="english">English: ' + phrase[3] + '</span> </div>';
    return div;
}

$("#div01").append(makePhrase(phrases[0]));
$("#div02").append(makePhrase(phrases[1]));​
```

And proof it works over at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SKssF/14

Comment: Please see above comment as I still need this to put the results inside #div01, or #div2, or #div3 etc - see my jsfiddle:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/SKssF/6 @Hank

Comment: Nice, you are so close. you just needed to 'return' the 'div' var from the function. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SKssF/14/

Comment: Yeeeah, that's it! A big thank you to everyone who answered, i now have the confidence to explore JQuery in more depth now I can see this working. Your charity is fantastic Hank and Felix and @mshsayem

Comment: Great to hear. I have updated my answer to reflect the correct solution, could you take the time to accept the answer? Thanks